# Why do I get InvalidCastException when I try to get Instruction from MethodBody? (Mono.Cecil)

Tags: c#, mono, mono.cecil

I'm using this code:

```
private static void DoWork(ref MethodDefinition methodDefinition, int index)
{
    var originalInstruction = methodDefinition.Body.Instructions[index];
    // ^
    // | exception is on this line
    // |
}
```

I'm getting InvalidCastException every time.
methodDefinition.Body.Instructions is a **Mono.Collections.Generic.Collection**
How to fix it?

Stack trace: http://image.prntscr.com/image/e20e4b00143140a79497b71f0906119e.png

I tried to debug it for so long time.
It seems that when I pass MethodDefinition to function - it's not null.
But when first line from function is executing it's setting to null for some reason. What?..

Comment: Look at the full exception stack to see where exactly the exception is thrown.

Comment: Not enough information here to tell. I see nothing that would trigger the exception in question, therefore it must be in other code.

Comment: Exception thrown directly from this line. Yes, it takes integer for indexer.

Comment: Can you include the stack trace?

Comment: Included stack trace.

Comment: Why is `methodDefinition` being passed using `ref`?